# Error while running .Net core 6.0 application in ubuntu using wine

Tags: wine

We have .net framework based application which connects with backend using REST API. When we run this application using Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 it works perfectly well. Our requirement is that we need to covert this .net framework based application to .net core 6 first and then run using Wine on Ubuntu.
After this transformation, when we run the application and try to Deserialize JSON returned from REST API, it is failing with following error

```
Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)
0204:fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L".NET Runtime"): stub
0204:fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (CAFE4242,0x0001,0x0000,0x000003ff,00000000,0x0001,0x00000000,003AD66C,00000000): stub
0204:err:eventlog:ReportEventW L"Application: APP.exe\nCoreCLR Version: 6.0.522.21309\n.NET Version: 6.0.5\nDescription: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 0144D5A8 (01320000) with exit code 80131506.\n"
0204:fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (CAFE4242) stub
wine: Call from 7BC29F80 to unimplemented function KERNEL32.dll.RaiseFailFastException, aborting
Unhandled exception. System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
```

Strange thing is that this behavior is intermittant. Sometimes Deserialization succeeds as well.
We have seen same behavior with Newtonsoft.Json APIs as well

Code line is as follows:

```
value = (T)System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(T));
```

We are using Wine 7 version.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Wrong place to ask this: this is a windows coding problem possibly related to wine. You need a wine expert and those are at https://forum.winehq.org/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might have to update your wine version.

This error has been resolved fairly recently (6 May 2022):
https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=48718

Commit solving this problem:
https://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git/commitdiff/509877743efab802a9d84c8a2b05fdadeb122869

To resolve this issue you'll have to switch to developer release 7.10